# Javac : ignoring "should be declared in a file named..."

Tags: api, java, javac, java-compiler-api

I'm using tools from the compiler API (javax.tools.JavaCompiler) to dynamically generated Java bytecode. I build source code and use API to compile it, then use it via reflexion.

That's perfectly fine as long as I only try te generated non-public classes. If i do, I get a "class MyClass is public, should be declared in a file named MyClass.java" which is perfectly normal, its not compiled from a Java file.

I'm looking for a way to bypass this error, haven't find any in Java options nor in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article: [Create class from string](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/)

For me using "string:///" resolve this issue.

as this is described here http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/

Comment: Well, I tried to re-run my generation code... and that's working fine. I don't know exactly what I changed in my compilation library since, but I can't reproduce this error. Anyway your links are great (got somthing similar to the second one).